# Retrieve radiobuttons from the child div within the main div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html.. 1 main div having 2 child divs.
I need to loop through both the divs and retrieve the checked radiobutton in each. e.g.: 1st child div has maybe checked while 2nd div has wright checked, i need to retrieve both their values. How do i go about it

```
<DIV>
 <DIV>
  <TABLE>
   <TBODY>
      <TR>
          <TD>
            wrong<INPUT class=XX disabled value=wrong type=radio name=radiobutton>
            wright<INPUT class=XX disabled value=wright type=radio name=radiobutton>
            maybe<INPUT class=XX value=maybe CHECKED type=radio name=radiobutton ></TD>
    </TR></TBODY></TABLE>
</DIV>
<DIV>
   <TABLE><TBODY><TR>
     <TD>
      wrong<INPUT class=XX CHECKED value=wrong type=radio name=radiobutton>
       wright<INPUT class=XX value=wright type=radio name=radiobutton>
       maybe<INPUT class=XX value=maybe type=radio name=radiobutton ></TD>
       </TR></TBODY></TABLE>
     </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two groups of radiobuttons from what I understand.

So, here's my solution:

> HTML

```
<div>
  <div>
      <table>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td>wrong
                      <input class="xx" disabled="disabled" value="wrong" type="radio"
                      name="radiobutton">wright
                      <input class="xx" disabled="disabled" value="wright" type="radio"
                      name="radiobutton">maybe
                      <input class="xx" value="maybe" checked="checked" type="radio" name="radiobutton">
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
  <div>
      <table>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td>wrong
                      <input class="xx" checked="checked" value="wrong" type="radio" name="radiobutton2">wright
                      <input class="xx" value="wright" type="radio" name="radiobutton2">maybe
                      <input class="xx" value="maybe" type="radio" name="radiobutton2">
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>​
```

> jQuery

```
var radiobutton = $("input[name='radiobutton']:checked").val();
var radiobutton2 = $("input[name='radiobutton2']:checked").val();

alert('1st - '+radiobutton+' / 2nd - '+radiobutton2);​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L48pw/1)

**EDIT**

> jQuery

```
var checked = new Array();
var pos = 0;
$("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function(){
    checked[pos] = new Array(2);
    checked[pos]['name'] = $(this).attr('name');
    checked[pos]['value'] = $(this).val();
    pos++;
});

var result = "";
for(i=0; i<pos; i++){
    result += checked[i]['name'] + " - " + checked[i]['value'] + " / ";
}
alert(result);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L48pw/3/)

Comment: if i dont know the name in the input attribute, how can i loop through the divs to find the name of the input tag.... imagine the name is dynamically generated so there is no predefined name for the three input tags....

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for: **Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/79syA/

In your HTML you only have `wrong` input radio checked, also make your html lowercase is there any reason why it is upper case `:)`

Rest hope this fits your need & feel free to play around with demo! `:)`

**code**

```
$('.XX').each(function(){

    if($(this).is(':checked')){
       alert(" Checked value is ==> " + this.value);
    }        

})​
```